# Windows Task Scheduler cannot run batch with special characters in filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch script which makes a backup of my SQL databases. It runs perfectly when I manually run the script! The filename looks like `SRVNAME_PRJ123!abc=CITY!Database=DBNAME`

But when I create a scheduled task, it does not work! CMD says that `SRVNAME_PRJ123!abc` is not a command or cannot be found. As you can see after the first equal sign (=) in the filename everthing is truncated.

It seems like that the task scheduler thinks that the filename is command, but I need this special characters in the filename.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try replacing the = with ==, some characters needs to be escaped when used within Task Scheduler

Comment: Place a pair of `"` around the path...

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this behavior. I expected that quoting the filename would solve it, but apparently it doesn't. The only way I found so far to make this work is to escape the `=` sign in the filename by inserting a `^`: `SRVNAME_PRJ123!abc^=CITY!Database=DBNAME`

Strangely enough, when running from a command prompt, quoting works, but escaping doesn't.